# Routing angular 5 , passing a string on params after URL

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am developing an Angular project based on geographic system information.

The idea is:

- I have a component which its route is: `{path: 'home'}`.
- I want to pass a geojson URL with this route to be like that : `{path: 'home/:url'}`
- And in the Onit function of the component I get my URL and use it in a specific function.
- But the problem that I meet is when I put string I can get it but a long URL it redirect me to the login page.

My code is:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.load(params['url']);
    });
}
 
load (url) {
    // code of the function here
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with this implementation is that you are essentially appending your *application* url with another url. If your routes are defined as `/home/:url`, you can imagine how confused Angular Router will get if you pass in a geojson URL and your application url suddenly looks like `/home/http://geojson.io/#map=13/40.7159/-74.0084` - Router can't map that url to any defined route and will just navigate to your default/wildcard route (in your case, `/login`).

A good way to pass long strings around is to set the url as a `queryParam` instead of a route param -- https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/.

I suggest removing the `/home/:url` route and giving something like this a try:

```
// in your template
<a [routerLink]="['/home']"
   [queryParams]="{ url: 'http://geojson.io/#map=13/40.7159/-74.0084' }">

// in your component
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  let url = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.url;
  this.load(url);
}

private load(url: string) {
  // do something with the url...
}
```

Comment: Your answer is logic but in my case the problem that i get the url from an external project and i want to connect the two projects toguether :/

Comment: No worries. If it's a simple matter of providing appropriate links in your external project, you can certainly do that. `<a href="http://your-angular-project.com/home?url=<YOUR_URL>"`. That link will connect you to your Angular app and things should run fine. If that isn't what you're after, perhaps you could update your question info with a bit more detail about what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

To find out, where is the problem, log your `route` to `console` and see if it accepts any of your routing. It is common a problem. Your `route` doesn't match any and as you have somewhere in your code something like this in your routing module:

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
```

you'll get redirected without any errors at all. Remove line like this (for testing purposes) and you'll get an error which tells you, what's exactly wrong.